# How to update and commit only file permissions?

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, file-permissions

I tried

```
git update-index --chmod=+x docker.sh
```

and after that

```
git ls-tree HEAD
```

It shows

```
100644 blog d8....
```

and

```
ls -lah docker.sh

-rwxr-xr-x 1 f85147 1049089 2.1K Dec 19 14:22 docker.sh*
```

Why?

I tried from WINDOWS CMD nad with git bash and got the same.
I want to change locally and push to Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git ls-tree HEAD` shows the tree from `HEAD`, that is **the last commit**. Your change is not yet committed. `git update-index` updates **index**, not `HEAD`. After `git update-index --chmod=+x docker.sh` do `git commit` then repeat `git ls-tree HEAD`.